# use variable's value in if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dynamic-values

I have dynamic condition for `if`, how can I check it by using as this:-

```
var searchQuery = '(data.id == "1") && (data.first == "et")';
if(searchQuery === true)
    alert('yes');
```

this is only checking that variable is empty or not. but I need to check variable's value as statement and check it by if condition.

variable value is not static , even in value more than 2 arguments may exist. how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [evil](https://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil) [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
var searchQuery = '(data.id == "1") && (data.first == "et")';

if(eval(searchQuery))
    alert('yes');
```

It evaluates a string as JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval

```
var searchQuery = '(data.id == "1") && (data.first == "et")';

if(eval(searchQuery) === true)
    alert('yes');
```

or Function constructor:

```
if (new Function('return ' + searchQuery)() === true)
    alert('yes');
```